# XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Invalid HTTP status code 400 (WebApi with angularJs on Chrome)

Tags: c#, angularjs, google-chrome, asp.net-web-api

I have WebApi Application and a simple consuming web client. I am sending requests to webApi using angularJS from web client. And cors is already enabled of course.

I have had problems with Post on chrome but I fixed it using param to the object sent, I thought it would be the same for Put but I got 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL. Invalid HTTP status code 400' on chrome whereas it's working okay on IE.

C# code :

```
public void UpdateLampe(int Id, Lampe lampe)
    {

        var context = new eDomDataContext();
        var found = context.Lampes.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == Id);
        if (found != null)
        {
            found.Etat = lampe.Etat;
            found.Date = DateTime.Now;

            context.Lampes.Attach(found);
            context.Entry(found).State = EntityState.Modified;

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

```js
//Post request (works ok)

var lampe = $.param({'TypeObject': typeObject, 'SalleId': salleId});
        $http({
          method: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:1770/api/Lampe",
          data: lampe,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',}
        }).success(function (data) {
          alert("it works");
          }).error(function () {
          console.log(Error);
          alert('Error reading JSON file.');
        })
          .then(function (response) {
                  return response;
          });


//Put request  <= still have problem

var etat = $.param({'Etat' : false});
$http({
          method: "PUT",
          url: "http://localhost:1770/api/Lampe/1" ,
          data: etat,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',}
        }).success(function (data) {
          alert("it works");
          }).error(function () {
          console.log(Error);
          alert('Error reading JSON file. - ');
        })
          .then(function (response) {
                  return response;
          });
```

Is there anything with what I did?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here : http://ask.webatall.com/iis/18460_asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8.html

It was all about allowing the PUT & DELETE in the web.config

It might help someone.